# How can I show a pop-up message after an user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, authentication, identity

I'm working on an asp.net core mvc website for a homework. The app is using identity server for login. I'm trying to show a pop-up alert after an user enters the correct credentials and presses the Login button(something like javascript alert). I've created a boolean property inside the .cs file which becomes true when an user succesfully logs in. In the .cshtml file I've added a script block which contains a function that shows an alert when the boolean property is true. The issue is that the function is executed when the page is created(at that moment the property is false) even though I'm calling the function on button click.
Any suggestions which might be the issue?

```
Login.cshtml
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<div class="container w-50 text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4" style="margin-bottom: 80px;">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
    <section>
        <form id="account" method="post">
            <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                        <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button onclick="showAlert()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>
                    <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    showAlert = function () {
        if (@LoginModel.alert) {
            alert("Logged in succesfully");
            @LoginModel.alert = false;
        }
    }
</script>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

```
Login.cshtml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using BookingApp.ApplicationLogic.DataModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace BookingApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;
        [BindProperty] static public bool alert { get; set; } = false;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<User> signInManager,
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    alert = true;
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your appreoach doesn't help to you do it. You must create a a PartialView which returns json result. And do the login process via Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `@LoginModel.alert` gives out a JS-boolean? Because it usually doesn't when writing JS with razor.

If the output is not exactly understood as boolean by Javascript at this point, it is "truthy". E.g. if it is parsed as a string, the condition is "true" for JS.

In JS I would always suggest checking values with `===`, just to be on the type-safe side. For example:

```js
if (@Json.Encode(LoginModel.alert) === true) {
   // ...
}
```